# GNU Linker Colorization

Tags: colors, gnu, linker, ld

Compiling code with GCC or Clang can result in some colorful error outputs.

Linking code, however, doesn't enjoy the same luxury. It seems like the GNU Linker doesn't support colorized error output right out of the box.

Is there a way around this? Is it possible to colorize/stylize linker errors from ld?

Comment: "Probably?" What would you color, specifically?

Comment: Personally? The file name and the offset within the file. But of course any scheme that would make linker errors easier to read is fine

Comment: It's just that your question is broadly phrased; if I colored the first letter of every line green, that's *technically* an answer to your question, but probably not what you're after, which is why I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple wrapper script to colorize ld output.

I have the following script saved as `/usr/local/bin/ld` which assumes that the real `ld` is at `/usr/bin/ld`.

Now I can change my `PATH` to point to this directory:
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"`

Save as `/usr/local/bin/ld` and do `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ld`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import re

RED = '\033[91m'
GREEN = '\033[92m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'

def colorize_output(line):
    pattern = r'([\/\w\.-]+):(\d+)'
    colored_line = re.sub(pattern, RED + r'\1' + ENDC + ':' + GREEN + r'\2' + ENDC, line)
    return colored_line

def run_ld(args):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/ld'] + args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if not output and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(colorize_output(output.decode()), end='')

    while True:
        output = process.stderr.readline()
        if not output and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(colorize_output(output.decode()), end='')

    return process.poll()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pass all arguments to the ld command
    exit_code = run_ld(sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

The only thing is that this script would first print `stderr` and then `stdout`.

A more sophisticated script could scan the path to find the right `ld`.